2019 Community Moderator Election Results
Quantitative Finance's second moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:
 
They'll be joining the existing crew shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking SRKX who will be stepping down as moderator.
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.

Congratulations to Attack68 and welcome to the team! I look forward to moderating together and to grow the site further!

@Attack68: Congratulations and very warm welcome!

@Attack68: Congratulations!
